# Do neutrino really decay?

Tags: dirac-equation, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

It is suggested that neutrino decay in both Dirac as well as Majorana models,in the former the byproduct is undetectable whatever that may mean and in the latter it is anti particle. Which is correct?

Comment: Where is this suggested? I'm pretty sure neutrinos are stable indefinitely, given the fact they're fundamental particles.

Comment: Are you asking whether neutrinos are Dirac or Majorana? That is unknown.

Comment: I was reading on the original super kamiokande team where they proposed scenarios whereby neutrino decays but now wants to know the update.

Comment: @shadowbiscuit Being a fundamental particle does not mean that it cannot decay, the muon is a fundamental particle and it decays.

Comment: @user6760 You should cite the article you're talking about. From what I know, the Superkamiokande experiment was set up to study the proton decay.

Comment: @DavideMorgante whoops, of course. And there was me literally studying muon decays for a problem sheet last month :')

Answer (score 1):

Typically neutrinos are not known to interact with other matter outside of the weak force and therefor do not typically decay back into other particles and only oscillate between neutrino flavors, however there are theoretical ways in which on large scales electrons in plasma around stars can transfer energy with neutrinos through a theoretical electroweak force.

[https://phys.org/news/2023-09-insights-neutrino-interactions.html#:~:text=%22Under%20normal%20'classical'%20conditions,known%20as%20plasma%2C%20which%20occurs](https://phys.org/news/2023-09-insights-neutrino-interactions.html#:%7E:text=%22Under%20normal%20%27classical%27%20conditions,known%20as%20plasma%2C%20which%20occurs)